# How to apply ellipsis to outer span with inline block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ellipsis

I have a html tag, in which i want to add ellipsis to the outer element and inside span which is also have inline-block.

HTML :

```
<span class="ellipsis">
   <span class="tag">Test</span>
   <span class="tag">Test1</span>
   <span class="tag">Test2</span>
   <span class="tag">Test3</span>
   <span class="tag">Test4</span>
   <span class="tag">Test5</span>
   <span class="tag">Test6</span>
   <span class="tag">Test7</span>
</span>
```

CSS :

```
.ellipsis {
      width: 100px;
      display: inline-block;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }

.tag {
      display : inline-block;
      background-color : green;
 }
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AbAJAXa/5/edit)

This doesnt work..

Comment: Not quite clear.. What do you want to ellipse out? remember ellipsis works on the text not on another inner element.

Comment: i want to apply ellipsis on the outer element.. Check the demo, the outer span with class named as ellipsis

Comment: Yes ellipsis wil lwork on text directly under the outerspan. You want it to consider the test inside each individual inner spans as well?

Comment: So you want like a round-border?

Comment: Is it possible to apply ellipsis on the outer span ?

Comment: If the inner elements are `inline` display, it works: http://jsbin.com/AbAJAXa/13/edit I am not sure if it will work with anything other than `inline` display.

Comment: Can you post an example that is closer to what you want to achieve eventually? I mean, this one can be solved easily by changing the styles back to `inline`. That is not what you want, obviously.

Comment: The demo which i showed above is the same in which i want to include "..." (ellipsis) with inline block.

Comment: I've executed your example in my local machine and I'm able to see the expected results. And when I copy and paste same code in jsfiddle, results are as expected. I believe code is correct and working fine.

Comment: can you share the screenshot of how it looks ?